# How to catch distinct data in a specific column of a SQLite database very fast?

Tags: sql, algorithm, performance, sqlite

I have the following situation: there is a table where one of its columns is a date-time string. What I want to do is to know which years are mentioned in this table, that is: I want to read all lines in the column "date-time" and see which of them have a year different from my "already mentioned years list"; if a given row has a year not yet added, I add that year to my list and at the end I'll have all mentioned years.

Now naturally enough I know how to do this in a very costful algorithm which would be a literal implementation of the text above. What I would like to know is if there is a fast way, maybe more "native", of doing such kind of query - you can just imagine the huge processor cost I'll get if I try to implement an algorithm exactly as told above.

Any better ideas?

Details: I'm programming with C++/Qt and the table may be big (like 10000 rows or more).

Answer (score 2):

You could select min(date-time) and max(date-time) and get the years from those, then iterate over all the years in between, checking to see if there exists a record with a date-time during the year in question.  Not sure it would be faster, but might be worth a try.

Or you could select distinct X where X is a function which returns the year part of the date.  That's probably the most native, cleanest way to do it; I'm afraid date manipulation functions tend to be sql-platform specific, so I'm not sure of the syntax for sqlite.

Looks like it might be

```
select distinct strftime('%Y', date-time) as Year
```

Answer (score 1):

For best performance, there needs to be a suitable index on the `datetime` string column. I'm going to suggest (not necessarily recommend) an approach that avoids some potential performance issues with some other query patterns.

The approach I suggest is to make use of multiple queries, each query returning a single row containing a new year value. (I'm assuming that there will be only a few distinct year values, and a lot of rows for a given year.)

Let's assume that my existing list of years contains 2011, 2013 and 2014.

The following describes the sequence of queries I would run, making use of the existing values as predicates in the queries I run. The basic idea is that I only need to find one row in a given year... there's no need to read *all* of the rows.

I'd need to existing list of years to be in order. I'd start with the lowest value, and run a query that gets the earliest date before that year. I'd want a query that makes the most effective use of the index, and optimizations available in Sqllite.

The earliest year value I have in my existing list is '2011'. I'd push that into the query... my first shot would be something like:

```
 select dt from t where dt < '2011-01-01'
  order by dt limit 1
```

If I don't get row back, I know that 2011 is the earliest year.

If I do get a row back, I know it's a "new" year. I'd take the first four characters as the year, and add it to my list. I'd compare that year value to 2011, if the difference is more than one, I'd check for the next lowest year.

For example, if that query returned a date that starts with '2008', the next query I run checks for the row with the lowest datetime with a year after 2008, but before 2011.

```
 select dt from t where dt < '2011-01-01'
    and dt >= datetime('2008-01-01','+1 years') 
  order by dt limit 1
```

If I don't get a row back, I know there are no more "new" year values before 2011. My next query would use 2011 as the lower bound, and the next year value in my existing list as the upper bound, and repeat that same query again.

If I do get row back, with datetime that starts with 2009. I'd add 2009 to my list, and my next query is exactly like the one above, but with 2009 in place of 2008...

```
 select dt from t where dt < '2011-01-01'
    and dt >= datetime('2009-01-01','+1 years') 
  order by dt limit 1
```

Again, if I don't get a row, then I know there are no more new years before 2011.

So, now 2011 is my lower bound, and the next year in my existing list is the upper bound. So, same query again, only changing the year literals...

```
 select dt from t where dt < '2013-01-01'
    and dt >= datetime('2011-01-01','+1 years') 
  order by dt limit 1
```

If I get a row, that's a new year to add to my list. And that's my new lower bound for the next query. If no row, then my upper bound on the last query is the new lower bound.

For optimizing the pattern, I would skip running a query that I know won't return a row. When I already have year 2013 and 2014 in my list, my query would be of this pattern...

```
 select dt from t where dt < '2014-01-01'
    and dt >= datetime('2013-01-01','+1 years') 
  order by dt limit 1
```

but we know that there are no rows that satisfy both conditions. A row can't have dt value that is less than 2014 and greater than or equal to 2014, it's an impossible condition, so we can skip executing it.

When I get to the last value in my list, I will remove the upper bound condition... I don't care if the next query returns 2015, 2017, or 2032... whatever the lowest year after the latest year I have in my list.

```
 select dt from t where 
        dt >= datetime('2014-01-01','+1 years') 
  order by dt limit 1
```

If I get a row back, add that year to the list, and use it as my next lower bound. And repeat until I don't get a row back.

This does run several queries, but they should be very efficient. On Hugh Jass tables, these may be the most efficient queries you can run to find new year values.

Where this pattern breaks down is when we need to run a lot of queries, when there are a lot of "gaps" we need to check.

Worst case for this pattern would be hundreds of existing year values ending it odd digits. There's a gap between each year value, and we have to check each gap between them.

But best case for this pattern is a long list of contiguous year values. If there are no new year values to be found, we'd run at most *two* queries. One to check for an earlier year (not found), and another to check for a later year (not found).

---

Again, performance of this approach absolutely depends on having an appropriate index on `dt`, and query plans that make effective use of that index.

Comment: We wouldn't necessarily need to use the `datetime` function to add a year to the date literal, we could just as easily handle that on the client, adding 1 to the year value.  (I did it with the datetime function to illustrate that we were using a year value we'd retrieved, or was in our list. This also assumes that the "datetime string" column is stored in consistent format, with the leading date portion in format "`yyyy-mm-dd`".

Comment: If we start with an existing list of year values which is *empty*, our first query would have no predicate (condition) on the dt column, just get the earliest.

Comment: thanks for the careful explanation of this interesting algorithm! Btw your presuppositions are correct: although the database may be used for lets say 30 years, in most of the time I will have a big list of consecutive entries of the same year (which will have the same format, `yyyy/MM/dd`.

Comment: @Mmergil: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. I took you to mean you had a list of distinct "previously mentioned years" values, which I took to be a short array of values... '2011','2013','2014'... and that what you wanted was an efficient means of inspecting the table, to determine if elements needed to added to that array.

Comment: @Momergil: The format `yyyy/mm/dd` is not one of the formats that Sqllite uses for date or time strings. I assumed you were using a supported format `yyyy-mm-dd`. Obviously, you can store whatever strings you want, but the query above was designed to work with a Sqllite date time string. [https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) The queries would need to be adapted to remove the references to Sqllite datetime functions.

Comment: Well maybe I'm mistaken about the date-time format (I'm not with the code now), but I'll check that (thanks for the note!). About the algorithm, you understood it right - but it may be useful to notice that the "previously mentioned array" starts empty.

Comment: Starting with an empty array, if there are 30 distinct year values in the table, this algorithm will execute 31 queries to return those. (This algorithm was intended as a way to quickly check if any new "year" values had been added, with the expectation that most of the times this runs, it won't find any. The intent of the design was to avoid re-checking for year values we already know about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SqlLite specifics, but it is close to ANSI in some respects:  A fast way to distinct a computed value such as that, is to say

```
select strftime('%Y',datetime) 
from TABLE 
group by strftime('%Y',datetime)
```

group by used without aggregate functions in sqlserver will return distinct single columns.

if sqlite is not as conducive, you could also select a count of another column, to limit the years to distinct